# Python pandas : Pivot table with respective count?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a `df` with the name of the owner, pet name, gender and whether it is vaccinated or not.
I want to use a pivot table to get each count

```
                owner      pet       vacine    Gender  

            0   john       dog       True        M

            1   tom        dog       False       F

            2   robert     cat       False       F

            3   joseph     dog       True        F

            4   mary       bird      False       F

            5   lily       cat       True        M
```

My resultant df would be similar like this

```
                    pet     Total     vacine     Gender(Male)

            0      dog      3         2           1

            1      cat      2         1           1

            2      bird     1         0           0
```

`'Total'` would the total number of pets in `pet` column.
`'Gender'` would the male in 'Gender' column.

Comment: why is dog gender 1? there are 2 F and 1 M

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do:

```
df.groupby('pet').agg(
         vacine = ('vacine', 'sum'),
         Total =  ('pet', 'size'), 
         Gender = ('Gender', lambda x: sum(x == 'M'))
).reset_index()

    pet  vacine  Total  Gender
0  bird     0.0      1       0
1   cat     1.0      2       1
2   dog     2.0      3       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your handling the gender column, here are 2 options

```
 df.groupby(['pet']).agg({'vacine': 'sum', 'Gender': lambda x: sum(x == 'M'), 'pet': 'count'})
      vacine  Gender  pet
pet                      
bird     0.0       0    1
cat      1.0       1    2
dog      2.0       1    3
```

```
df.groupby(['pet']).agg({'vacine': 'sum', 'Gender': 'unique', 'pet': 'count'})
      vacine  Gender  pet
pet                      
bird     0.0     [F]    1
cat      1.0  [F, M]    2
dog      2.0  [M, F]    3
```